# What's the history of the non-official pronunciation of SQL?

Tags: sql, history

SQL is officially pronounced as /ˌɛskjuːˈɛl/ like "S-Q-L", as stated in

> Beaulieu, Alan (April 2009). Mary E. Treseler. ed. Learning SQL (2nd ed.). Sebastapol, CA, USA: O'Reilly. ISBN 978-0-596-52083-0.

But often it is pronounced  /ˈsiːkwəl/ like "sequel", what is the history behind this second pronunciation?

Comment: I'm not sure but I have heard that it was named sequel before, and later changed to SQL.

Comment: It's easier to pronounce a word then three individual letters. Hence "TYR" becomes "tier" and "SQL" becomes "sequal." I said "My S-Q-L" for years before I got sick of funny looks and just started calling it "sequal."

Comment: I hate the "sequel" pronunciation.  SQL Server... Sequel Server?  What's that, the version used by Hollywood studios?

Comment: @Josh K - Exactly. People use what's easier for them when they see the information still gets across. Dialects also have a strong influence in this. See my update for another example.

Comment: Anyone who finds "SQL" hard to pronounce has a broken mouth.  And if you're saying it that often, just say "db" or "query" instead, even faster and has the added bonus of differentiating engine/code.

Comment: Other pronunciations: *squeal* and *squirrel*.

Comment: Oh, and if people *really* wanted an easy/lazy pronunciation, it'd just be _'squl'_ (_'skwul'_) - no 'ee' sound needed. Go ahead and say 'sequel' if you want to be old-fashioned, but don't claim it's a linguistic matter.

Comment: If the Evil Empire can be trusted...it's SEQUEL! :-) http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#i60831

Comment: @Peter - I once spoke to a recruitment consultant who pronounced SQL as "skwul".  In that case I decided it wasn't a linguistic matter, more a case that I should speak to a recruitment consultant who wasn't utterly clueless.

Comment: I say "sequel". I also say "teesquel" for T-SQL :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To quote Wikipedia on this:

> SQL was adopted as a standard by the American National Standards Institute (ANSI) in 1986 as SQL-86[19] and International Organization for Standardization (ISO) in 1987. The original SQL standard declared that the official pronunciation for SQL is "es queue el".[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27all) Many English-speaking database professionals still use the nonstandard[20] pronunciation /ˈsiːkwəl/ (like the word "sequel").`

Several other [links](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/sqlfundamentals.htm) also confirm that a consensus on the matter of pronunciation still isn't close.

*Btw, why does it matter?*

Edit: Another example of natural language evolution [y'all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27all)

Comment: It matters because hearing "sequel" is like fingernails on a blackboard for some of us... And so we grow out our nails and carry small slates to enable reciprocity.

Comment: @Mr.C - Wait! You're an english speaking person, and you're just now noticing the habit of english speakers to shorten pronunciation in various ways, according to where from does the particular person comes from (UK, USA, India,AU)? It is a natural evolvment of the language, nothing else - some pronunciate it this way, others that way ... and then one of those ways gets accepted. To me, for example "sequel" is much easier to pronunciate, as well as more "fluent" than "es queue el" (notice: I'm not a native eng. speaker). Similar example, colour vs. color (in this case both the writing and the

Comment: pronunciation are different, UK vs. US)

Comment: It matters because when people on your team use the wrong terminology for IT-related things, it makes it look like the team doesn't know anything about IT. It's like calling a monitor "the computer."

Comment: I don't think the pronunciation has as much to do with language evolution as it does nostalgia and possibly anachronistic regionalism.

Comment: @HardCode - Please, do differentiate terminology and pronunciation. They have little in common. And we're talking only about the latter in here. Also, calling a monitor "the computer" (and just so it is noted, that in some cases that could be correct - there were examples of such configurations in history) could be viewed as a lack of understanding the basic parts of a computer. If one understands "his stuff", nobody will object to his pronunciation and think less of him, because of his pronunciation. Well, nobody should.

Comment: @Peter Turner - I'm sorry. You've lost me. (anachronistic regionalism?!)

Comment: Well, there's a place in Janesville Wisconsin called Mac's Pizza Shack.  When I was a kid it was called Happy Joe's.  So I still call it Happy Joe's even though it's legally Mac's Pizza Shack.  They still make the same awesome taco pizza. If my kids call Mac's Pizza Shack happy Joe's I'd call that an anachronistic regionalism.  Same goes for SEQUEL, people call it that because they hear other people calling it (such as their professors) that even though it's not the official name.

Comment: @Peter Turner - That is all right and well, but what has that got to do with my answer which concentrates on the pronounciation issue between SQL being called "es queue el" and "sequel" between various groups of people? (Btw, I'm not arguing the name itself. Nor is it of any interest to me. I'm only giving the basics on what one pronou. can amerge from the other given various circumstances).

Comment: @Mr. C - Do you say "laser" or "L-A-S-E-R"? Some frequently-used acronyms tend to pronounced as if they're words, and that's not a bad thing.

Comment: @Joel: I don't mind acronyms, but SQL isn't an acronym - it's an initialization that folks try to pronounce by making up the missing letters. If you want to argue that the long-defunct language SEQUEL should be pronounced the same as the word "sequel", you stand on much firmer ground...

Comment: @Peter: funny, I was just reminiscing about Happy Joe's last night. The one in Onalaska though. It used to be better.

Comment: @Rook: who the hell pronounces USA "ooohsah"? Or UK "uck"? We don't spell out "India" because *that's actually a word*... **[Edit:** oh, I see, you weren't implying that folks try to pronounce *those* initializations, merely that folks pronounce things differently depending on where they're from. Fair enough. But still, most initializations are spoken as such. **]**

Comment: @Mr.C - Yes, [...] <-that's right. But, let's stop with the pronounciations for now (cause it's not gettin' us anywhere). So let's just stop. What I don't understand (and this goes for everybody) is why it bothers you so much - as I said to ... uhh, ... somebody up in the comments - they're not using the wrong terminology, not using the wrong words. They're just! pronouncing them differently! Why does that bother anyone so much? It certainly doesn't bother me, and hell ... if anyone, I've heard my share of different accents. It is a widely known

Comment: fact that accents are not linked to languages ... so it is natural to expect that people will pronounce different words differently. In most cases (except the Scots :-) -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FFRoYhTJQQ) you can understand them. ***** Btw, yes, I've heard USA pronounced "uuusah" and UK "ukey". That's how it's pronounced in my part of the world, in any case.

Comment: @rook, I'm not going to go out and say, "my answer beats yours" because I think these questions can be approached from both the view point that it's a new word people made up and that it's an old word remade by corporate interests.

Comment: @Mr. C - So you're saying SQL isn't an acronym for Structured Query Language? In the unlikely event that's true, it really doesn't matter, because enough people believe it's true to pronounce it as a word the same way they pronounce LASER as a word. They are not wrong, because there is no wrong. I can't even comprehend getting emotionally involved in this debate.

Comment: @Joel: an acronym is a word made up of parts of other words. It's effectively a memorization aid. However, SQL isn't a word. It's just three consonants. If you add a few other letters, you can spell "ESQUEL" (a little town in Argentina) or "SEQUEL" (a follow-up or continuation, also the acronymous name of a precursor to SQL - see Peter's answer). But SQL is not itself an acronym.

Comment: @Joel no, You're saying SQL isn't an acronym.  You're the one claiming it's an acrostic (initial letters only) not an acronym (abbreviation pronounced as a word, rather than the initial letters).  And yes, that distinction annoys me a lot more than Sequel/SQL.

Comment: The pronunciation matters because it determines whether to write "*a* SQL database" or "*an* SQL database".

Answer (score 45):

SEQUEL = Structured English QUEry Language.

For a good historical perspective [read](http://www.mcjones.org/System_R/SQL_Reunion_95/sqlr95-System.html)

> Don Chamberlin: ...A bunch of things were happening at about this time that I think we ought to mention just in passing. One was that we had to change the name of our language from SEQUEL to SQL. And the reason that we had to do that was because of a legal challenge that came from a lawyer. Mike, you probably can help me out with this. I believe it was from the Hawker Siddeley Aircraft Company in Great Britain, that said SEQUEL was their registered trademark. We never found out what kind of an aircraft a SEQUEL was, but they said we couldn't use their name anymore, so we had to figure out what to do about that. I think I was the one who condensed all the vowels out of SEQUEL to turn it into SQL, based on the pattern of APL and languages that had three-lettered names that end in L. So that was how that happened. ...

Comment: So I guess SQL was the sequel to SEQUEL

Comment: @Tim: Hence why we say "sequel" I guess?

Comment: Actually, SEQUEL really was pretty much SQL as we know it. The name was dropped only because when IBM tried to get a trademark on it, they found out that somebody else had already trademarked that name (an aircraft company, IIRC). The official position that it should be pronounced "S-Q-L" comes only from the fact that doing otherwise could be interpreted as trademark infringement.

Comment: @Jerry you're right, I just took the time to read more of my link.

Comment: I blame my University Professor. I guess he didn't like those trademark lawyers and made a point to teach all of his students to pronounce it "sequel" just to be subversive :-)

Comment: This is the actual answer to the OP's question.

Comment: So basically, people who pronounce it "sequel" are upset that the guy was denied his trademark and want to pretend he got it anyway?